# Use edittext as html editor in android

Tags: java, android

i am creating an application which give options to write articles and submit.

I want to give all html options to user so that user can make part of text bold,italic,underlined etc.
i googled but not found that much suitable options or any html tool for android.

looking for suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like below for this :

Here textDisplayedBottom is a TextView.

```
actualStringToDisplay="font COLOR=\"RED\"><b>"+yourString</b></font>"; 
textDisplayedBottom.setText(Html.fromHtml(actualStringToDisplay));
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT 1: For EditText

For editext providing options for bold italic underline you can always use Spannable to achieve it

```
// Get our EditText object.
EditText vw = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);

// Set the EditText's 
text.vw.setText("Italic, highlighted, bold.");

// If this were just a TextView, we could do:
// vw.setText("Italic, highlighted, bold.", TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
// to force it to use Spannable storage so styles can be attached.
// Or we could specify that in the XML.
// Get the EditText's internal text storage

Spannable str = vw.getText();

// Create our span sections, and assign a format to each.

str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.ITALIC), 0, 7,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
str.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFF00), 8, 19, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 21, str.length() - 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

The details you can find here

http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#selectingtext

Comment: but i want to display text in html format in edit text itself!

Comment: Edited my answer. check if that helps.